# Spring JPA saveAndFlush() behaviour with @DynamicUpdate/@DynamicInsert

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a JPA entity that is not currently annotated with either @DynamicUpdate or @DynamicInsert. This table has around 30+ columns and a couple of CLOBs too.

Let's say, I already have an entry with *ID=123* in the table and need to update a few columns for the same record during request processing. I am updating the respective columns using DTO and then calling the **saveAndFlush()** method to push the changes into DB.

So, I have two queries related to the following operation

- For the respective operation, what should I use @DynamicUpdate or @DynamicInsert
- Whether either of the annotation i.e. @DynamicUpdate/@DynamicInsert will have any performance impact on the SQL execution

Answer (score 0):

The only impact is that different statements might be created (depending on combinations of attributes set) which reduces the probability for a statement cache hit.